# One JLabel disapears, when there are two

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

Ok, so I have been working on this lottery program in Java, and my code is in the extreme beginning phase, and i am stuck on this one problem. So when I create 2 JLabels, and run the program, only one shows. I have been trying to find an answer for some while now so i hope someone can help. Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Lottery extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5815877011755522230L;
    private JTextField text;
    private JLabel title, subTitle;
    public final String Title = "Lottery";

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        make();

    }     

    public Lottery() {

        title = new JLabel(Title, JLabel.CENTER);
        title.setFont(title.getFont().deriveFont(30.0f));
        add(title);


        subTitle = new JLabel("Lottery Numbers");
        subTitle.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.HORIZONTAL);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(subTitle, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }

    public static void make(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Lottery");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Lottery hi = new Lottery();
        frame.setContentPane(hi);

        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }
}
```

So, if anyone is able to help me with this problem, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to have a look at [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and [How to Use Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) and having a look at the [JavaDocs for `BorderLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) may also shed some illumination on the course of your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend you start by having a look at [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and [How to Use Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) and having a look at the [JavaDocs for `BorderLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) may also shed some illumination on the course of your problem

You have two key problems...

1. `BorderLayout` will only allow a single component to be managed at any of the five available positions and the default position is `CENTER`
2. `BorderLayout` will ignore ALL components added BEFORE it was set

So, if we took your code and changed it to something like

```
public Lottery() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    title = new JLabel(Title, JLabel.CENTER);
    title.setFont(title.getFont().deriveFont(30.0f));
    add(title);


    subTitle = new JLabel("Lottery Numbers");
    subTitle.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.HORIZONTAL);
    add(subTitle, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

you'd end up with the same problem, BUT, if we also provided additional constraints...

```
public Lottery() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    title = new JLabel(Title, JLabel.CENTER);
    title.setFont(title.getFont().deriveFont(30.0f));
    add(title, BorderLayout.NORTH);


    subTitle = new JLabel("Lottery Numbers");
    subTitle.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.HORIZONTAL);
    add(subTitle, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
```

will now place one label in the north position and one in the south

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to solve the problem, But i was wondering if you may know a way where i can get the text where I want using coordinates, or something like that.

Comment: Generally speaking you can't (or shouldn't).  You make suggestions to different layout managers, use empty borders change the label's alignment and bunch of the tricks, but generally speaking pixel perfect solutions are more hassel then they are worth

Answer (score 2):

```
add(title);
add(subTitle, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

look at this code , label .you didn't set the location of your label. so do the same thing as you did with subtitle . for example

```
add(title ,BorderLayout.NORTH );
```

Answer (score 0):

The second subTitle overwrites the first Title and you have to add it after you set the Layout.